# how to remove sublayout from the Layout in Android?

Tags: android

I am new to Android.Can anyone give some ideas for my problem.

```
    /* Parent Linear Layout */

    final LinearLayout par_layout=new LinearLayout(this);
    par_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    /* Child Linear Layout */
    final LinearLayout chl_layout=new LinearLayout(this);
    chl_layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView tv_name=new TextView(this);
    tv_name.setText("Name ");

    TextView tv_item=new TextView(this);
    tv_item.setText("Items ");

    Button btn_submit=new Button(this);
    btn_submit.setText("Submit");
    btn_submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            par_layout.removeAllViewsInLayout();                
        }
    });

    chl_layout.addView(tv_name);
    chl_layout.addView(tv_item);
    chl_layout.addView(btn_submit);        
    par_layout.addView(chl_layout); 
    setContentView(par_layout);
```

In the above code at the time of button click i wish to clear the chl_layout from the par_layout.But i can't . Can anyone give some ideas ??

Note :
The following code also not working

```
 par_layout.removeView(chl_layout);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use below code to remove child view from parent view.

```
 par_layout.removeView(chl_layout);
```

Answer (score 2):

to make whole layout empty 
there is a void function ...

LinearLayout li=new LinearLayout(this);

li.removeAllViews();

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
fatherLayout.removeViewInLayout(childLayout);
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't remove a child view (TableRow) from its parent (TableLayout) with removeView(View view).
But addView is working.
Strange...

Comment: this is not an answer to the question