# Remove layout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have got following xml structure of my app activity. Now I would like to remove child RelativeLayout programmatically with id layer1Front. How would I do that in code. I dont want to hide it, I need to remove it because of memory issues in my app. Also after removing it somehow will my app be lighter and faster than current one?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/layer1Front" >
    </RelativeLayout>   
    <HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <FrameLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"                   
            android:id="@+id/parallaxLayers"        
            android:visibility="gone">      
        </FrameLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/frontView">

    </RelativeLayout>       

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to remove sublayout from the Layout in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4030053/how-to-remove-sublayout-from-the-layout-in-android)

Comment: I hope you have tried View.GONE

Comment: I dont want to hide layout. I want to remove it

Comment: Why don't you want to hide it with GONE?

Comment: because removing elements from memory might make my that screen faster.

Comment: It's the other way round: you don't want to create too complicated layouts as if may make your screen slower.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Simplest would be

```
findViewById(R.id.layer1front).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

But then you can also have something like

```
View root = findViewById(R.id.your_root);
root.removeView(yourViewToRemove);
```

No, your app is not going to be lighter or faster after removing it

Answer (score 2):

Try fetching parent layout and than remove child

```
parentView.remove(child)
```

I hope this works.